# See application log in browser using Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I want to see my application log in the browser (like, how the Hudson show the build log in console). Is there any Grails plugin or any logic to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Ya just simple idea i thought let me tell you :

Install if you have the log4J logging 
  grails install-plugin log4j-xml

1.you have the log plugin on all app even on Javas ,so there is some way do it like
['The logging plugin configures Grails' support for Logging with Log4j.'](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Plug-ins/logging.html)

2.And to access that on Browser Console i suggest you call it on your .gsp file : within a jquery method . like :

on you .gsp import the logging library and define a variable that reads the logs or write into the logs.

```
<% def logvar = logging. // please look for a method which reads current loggin file or

//i suggest read the file line by line ,using standard filestream   %>

$.documentReady(function(){

Console.log("LogFile:"+"${logVar}");
});
```

But please See this one for all you NEED! [Please Visit Grails Link](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/single.html#logging)

Answer (score 0):

The best I've found for this is [psi-probe](https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/)

For logs it will give you log tailing, log download and changing the log level.  The tailing works well, so as you are viewing the log in your browser the new log entries appended to the log file are going to be seen almost immediately.

Be aware that it also has many other admin level features so you are going to need to lock it down or in a production environment disable it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

View your applications eclipse console log in local machine. It looks big procedure but very simple to do and much useful.

**Benefits:**

> 1. You can see the logs very friendly(check, search, copy...).
> 2. Much useful for all developers.
> 3. In remote Linux or VM machines, checking( search, copy...) eclipse console log is not much easy.
> 4. Nothing needed to do(change) in your application source code.

**How to do -**

1. Go to your Linux machine or VM
2. Open eclipse
3. Open Run Configurations.
4. Select Grails(or Java Application, Maven..... or anyone)
5. Click on new  icon
6. Enter some name (ex: MyApp_run)
7. Select project (ex: MyApp)
8. Write some command(goal)  (ex: run-app)
9. Next come to JRE tab and select “Workspace Default JRE”. If that not exist then select “Project JRE”(Optional, change if you get any problem while run.)
10. Next come to “Common” tab.
11. Select “Shared File”  specify any folder  (ex: '<'Workspace'>'/MyApp/launchers)
12. Select Debug or Run from “Display in favorites menu” based on your usage.
13. Select ‘File’ check box.
14. Create new log file(ex: /MyApp_eclipse.log) and give same in ’ File’ text box.
15. Click on ‘Apply’
16. Run
17. In your local machine
18. Open putty
19. In host name box give your VM ip address
20. Click on ‘Window’ in Category tree left side.
21. Change to Columns 180, rows 80 and   ‘Lines of Scroll back’  to 2000(maximum, you want)
22. Click open
23. Login to machine/VM
24. Run below commands

    cd  '<'some_common_folder'>'

    tail –f MyApp_eclipse.log –n 1000

You can do same steps for your other applications also, should give the different log file.

Note: while running the application, don’t change the content of log file, it stops logging to that file. You need to restart the application, if you change content.